# Deploy Geddy to Heroku

Tags: node.js, deployment, heroku, geddy

I'm trying to deploy a simple [Geddyjs](http://geddyjs.org/index.html) (node.js) app to [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/).

When I make a push a recive that error:

git push heroku master

```
Heroku receiving push
Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
```

What I have to do to that heroku detect the nodejs app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

couple of things did you do this for cedar you need to explicitly say this (I am sure you have done this but here for completeness)

`heroku create --stack cedar`

ensure that your package.json is at the root

[heroku have a good article on this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs)

You should now be able to

`git push heroku master`

Answer (score 1):

Have you added Procfile and package.json to your local git repo. and committed them?

I had created them but forgot to add & commit them so when pushed these files weren't uploaded hence Heroku didn't know the type of app.

Adding, committing & re-pushing fixed this.

Obvious when you know:-)