# Heroku Node Application Push Failure

Tags: javascript, git, node.js, heroku

So I'm trying to push my node app to heroku but I keep getting this error:

```
!     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:*************.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@***************.git'
```

I created this app with `heroku create --stack cedar` as reccomended by this article: [Deploy Geddy to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196563/deploy-geddy-to-heroku) but sadly that did no good for me.

UPDATE: my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "site",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.x",
    "jade": ">= 0.0.1",
    "coffee-script": "~1.4.0",
    "node-dev": "~0.2.9",
    "connect-flash": "~0.1.0",
    "connect-assets": "~2.3.3",
    "everyauth": "~0.2.34",
    "mongoose": "~3.5.3",
    "mongodb": "~1.2.7",
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "moment": "~1.7.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x",
    "npm": "1.1.x"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you make sure package.json is at the root?

Comment: Yes, and it's completely up to date.

Comment: is it called package.json (check casing / spelling) - i had this exact problem, mine was Package.json

Comment: also, could you post the content of your package.json?

Comment: It is spelled correctly. Add I ran `npm update --save` so that npm correctly writes all my package contents to `package.json` correctly. I'll post up my `package.json` just in case.

Comment: I meant I ran `npm install --save`****

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also with a node app and just got around it.

package.json was the problem and once added this is the steps I used:

```
git add package.json
git commit -m "Added package.json"
git push origin master
git push heroku master
```

This seemed to do the trick for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check.

- Ensure your package.json is called package.json (check spelling /
  case)
- Make sure you've comitted package.json to git:

  > $ git add package.json
  >     $ git commit -m "added package.json"

Comment: I added the `package.json` but sadly I still got the same error when trying to push to heroku.

Comment: Is it added to your git branch? And are you doing git push heroku master

Comment: I am doing `git push heroku master`, but how do I check to see if it's hooked up to my git branch?

Comment: Did you ADD the file to your git stage? ie- $ git add .